# Is there any sense in performing binary AND with a number where all bits are set to 1

Tags: math, binary

Greetings everybody. I have seen examples of such operations for so many times that I begin to think that I am getting something wrong with binary arithmetic. Is there any sense to perform the following:

```
byte value = someAnotherByteValue & 0xFF;
```

I don't really understand this, because it does not change anything anyway. Thanks for help.

P.S.
I was trying to search for information both elsewhere and here, but unsuccessfully.

**EDIT:**
Well, off course i assume that someAnotherByteValue is 8 bits long, the problem is that i don't get why so many people ( i mean professionals ) use such things in their code. For example in [SharpZlib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) there is:

```
     buffer_ |= (uint)((window_[windowStart_++] & 0xff |
     (window_[windowStart_++] & 0xff) << 8) << bitsInBuffer_);
```

where window_ is a byte buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is to make the code more self-documenting. In your particular example, it is not the size of `someAnotherByteValue` that matters, but rather the fact that `value` is a byte. This makes the `&` redundant in every language I am aware of. But, to give an example of where it would be needed, if this were Java and `someAnotherByteValue` was a `byte`, then the line `int value = someAnotherByteValue;` could give a completely different result than `int value = someAnotherByteValue & 0xff`. This is because Java's long, int, short, and byte types are signed, and the rules for conversion and sign extension have to be accounted for.

If you always use the idiom `value = someAnotherByteValue & 0xFF` then, no matter what the types of the variable are, you know that value is receiving the low 8 bits of someAnotherByteValue.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
uint s1 = (uint)(initial & 0xffff);
```

There is a point to this because `uint` is 32 bits, while 0xffff is 16 bits. The line selects the 16 least significant bits from `initial`.

Comment: Yep, my inattention. I'll change an example. +1

Answer (score 2):

Nope.. There is no use in doing this. Should you be using a value that is having its importance more than 8 bits, then the above statement has some meaning. Otherwise, its the same as the input.

Comment: Yeah, i understand it for values greater than 0xFF =)

Comment: Can you give me some links/source where this particular style is used.. Just curious

Answer (score 1):

If `sizeof(someAnotherByteValue)` is more than 8 bits and you want to extract the least signficant 8 bits from someAnotherByteValue then it makes sense. Otherwise, there is no use.

Comment: Please give an example where it makes a difference. In every language where the line actually compiles, the compiler assigns the low order 8 bits to `value` automatically. It might be justified as more self-documenting however.

Comment: @GregS : if `someAnotherByteValue` is 16 bit for example and has a value greater that 255 then of course it makes a difference isn't it?

Comment: I don't know of any language where it does make a difference, but then again I'm only familiar with a handful of languages.

Comment: @GregS: I've written code for compilers where sizeof(int)=1 and a `char` could hold values from -32768 to 32767 (I believe that when sizeof(int)==1, `char` must be signed, since an `int` is required to be able to hold all possible values of `char`).  The `C` standard specifies that `char` must be at least 8 bits, and must be able to represent all characters in the standard C character set, but nothing in the C standard says it must be precisely 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no point so long as you are dealing with a byte. If `value` was a long then the lower 8 bits would be the lower 8 bits of `someAnotherByteValue` and the rest would be zero.

In a language like C++ where operators can be overloaded, it's *possible* but unlikely that the & operator has been overloaded. That would be pretty unusual and bad practice though.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: Well, off course i assume that
>   someAnotherByteValue is 8 bits long,
>   the problem is that i don't get why so
>   many people ( i mean professionals )
>   use such things in their code. For
>   example in Jon Skeet's MiscUtil  there
>   is:
>
> uint s1 = (uint)(initial & 0xffff);
>
> where initial is int.

In this particular case, the author might be trying to convert an int to a uint. The & with 0xffff would ensure that it would still convert Lowest 2 Bytes, even if the system is not one which has a 2 byte int type.

Answer (score 0):

To be picky, there is no guaranty regarding a machine's byte size. There is no reason to assume in a extremely portable program that the architecture byte is 8 bits wide. To the best of my memory, according to the C standard (for example), a char is one byte, short is wider or the same as char, int is wider or the same as short, long is wider or the same as int and so on. Hence, theoretically there can be a compiler where a long is actually one byte wide, and that byte will be, say, 10 bits wide. Now, to ensure your program behaves the same on that machine, you need to use that (seemingly redundant) coding style.

["Byte"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) @ Wikipedia gives examples for such peculiar architectures.